# Select columns based on values from any table(number of columns is variable) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

I have a following table:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLw2m.png)

And I want to show only columns that have at least one value under 50:

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jZuJ.png)

I need a stored procedure that does this. The trick is that I want to use it on multiple tables but the number of columns can vary from table to table.

Can this be done?

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL for this purpose.

Comment: I'd appreciate any suggestions or code on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wish this will have some help.

```
SET NOCOUNT  ON 

DECLARE 
    @tablename VARCHAR(50) = 'Table1',
    @valuetocompare INT = 50,
    @otherfields VARCHAR(100) = 'Date, Hour,';

DECLARE @t AS TABLE (cname VARCHAR(10), cvalue INT)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @cname VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE c CURSOR  
FOR
    SELECT NAME
    FROM   sys.[columns] AS c
    WHERE  c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
;

OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT  FROM c INTO @cname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql =  'select ''' + @cname  + ''', ' + @cname + ' from '  + @tablename;

    INSERT INTO @t
      (
        cname,
        cvalue
      )
    EXECUTE (@sql);

    FETCH NEXT FROM c  INTO @cname;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

DECLARE @cnames VARCHAR(100) = '';
WITH dcnames AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT cname
         FROM   @t
         WHERE  cvalue < @valuetocompare
     )
SELECT @cnames = @cnames + cname +  ','
FROM   dcnames;

IF @cnames =  ''
    PRINT 'No column value is less than ' + CAST(@valuetocompare AS VARCHAR);
ELSE
BEGIN
      SET @sql =  'select ' + @otherfields  + LEFT(@cnames, LEN(@cnames) - 1)  + ' from ' + @tablename;
      EXECUTE (@sql);
END
```